# Group By like SQL for Datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, datagridview

This question has probably been asked before and answered but i can't seem to find it here.

I got a datagridview with 6 columns:

```
Name Description Price Date Amount TotalPrice
```

I want a second datagridview to be based on this. The TotalPrice and Date columns should be dropped, the Amount should be treated as SUM() like in SQL and the others should be Grouped By. 
This second datagridview should also alter when the original one get's filtered or refreshed.

Anyone know a solution or a post where this has been answered in?

Trying to do something with LINQ:

```
new_Datatable= old_Datatable.AsEnumerable()
             .GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("Name"))
             .Select(g =>
             {
                 var row = old_Datatable.NewRow();

                 row["Artikel"] = g.Key;
                 row["Aantal"] = g.Sum(r => r.Field<decimal>("Amount"));

                 return row;
             }).CopyToDataTable();
```

But i can't seem the right syntax to group by multiple fields and drop the unused columns (can of course remove them after the fact but if it can be done beforehand it would be more logical to do so. )

Comment: Is there a DataSource to the grid?

Comment: Yes a datatable.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if this works

```
new_Datatable= old_Datatable.AsEnumerable()
             .Select(c => c.Name, c.Description, c.Amount, c.TotalPrice)
             .GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("Name"), r.Field<string>("Description"), r.Field<string>("TotalPrice"))
             .Select(g =>
             {
                 var row = old_Datatable.NewRow();

                 row["Artikel"] = g.Key;
                 row["Aantal"] = g.Sum(r => r.Field<decimal>("Amount"));

                 return row;
             }).CopyToDataTable();
```